# Install a folder with a test project to writable directory

Tags: inno-setup

I write a program that can be installed with Inno Setup. I also have a folder with a project used to learn how to use this program. Unfortunately, this "example" project needs to have write rights. However, it is usually installed by default in the C:\ folder in Windows, which is read-only for most users.

What would be my best option using Inno-Setup to insure that the average user could write in this particular folder (not the other folders)?

Comment: If you create a folder in `C:` root, it's by default writable by anyone.

Comment: But you should not create a folder in `C:` root. That's against Windows guidelines. Why do you create a folder there?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. It installed it in C:\Program Files (x86)\My program. I meant, how to install it in the other disk (or in :C) where the user has its "usual files".

Comment: And do you want to install the data to be accessibly the the user installing it or for any user?

Comment: If possible, for any user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data that have to be writable, but also accessible by any user, the application should create a subfolder in `C:\ProgramData`.

Inno Setup has [`{commonappdata}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=commonappdata) for that:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\example\*"; DestDir: "{commonappdata}\My Program"
```

---

Though, I'm not if that's correct to share the files between users. You should better install the example somewhere to unwritable folder (like your current `Program Files`) and make a copy of that once any user needs it to that user's profile folder.

Comment: Thanks, it does work (for one user, but that is already a good start).